# Php & Angularjs Ajax : What is the proper way to retrieve data from ajax request to php?

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

just wan't to ask how  can i retrieve my data from my ajax request to my php api when coded like this :

controller :

```
        $scope.addCustomer= function() {

            IndexService.addCustomer($scope.persons)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.debug('response :', response);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.debug('error :', error);
            });
        }
```

Service :

```
        function addCustomer(data) {

            return $http({
                method:'POST',
                url: 'php/api/customer.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'applications/json'
            });

        }
```

i tried this to my php file but its telling me that undefined index 'data'

```
$data = $_POST['data']
```

question : what is the proper way to retrieve data from ajax call going to php file? thank you

Comment: What structure is `data` in your service? Have you tried `var_dump`ing `$_POST` to see if there's anything in it?

Comment: yes i tried to var dump it but it says array(0)

Comment: The Input won't be in $_POST; to retrieve it use, `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");`
`$response = json_decode($data, true );`